# Are there any known "available for purchase" life spans for expansions for Android Netrunner?

Tags: android-netrunner

As far as I know, a lot of cards (in TCG world) are stopped being produced (and available in stores) at some point. Is there a known life span for Android Netrunner expansions? For example is there a known life span such as 2 years at which the "Genesis" six-pack will no longer be produced and available in stores so if you don't get it until then you'll have to get it second-hand from somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All packs will just be produced for a couple of years. When the production is stopped, you can't play with the cards at tournaments any more.

When the production of the first pack in the eight cycle has started the production of the first two cycles will stop and the cards will be banned from tournaments. The same thing will happen when the production of the first pack in the tenth cycle has started but with the third and fourth cycle instead.

Here is a link to more information:
https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2014/11/5/a-new-stage-of-growth/

Answer (score 6):

Theoretically?  I don't see them ending production on a specific cycle.  The way Fantasy Flight talks and creates cards, they plan on keeping all of those options available for the future.  The LCG philosophy makes it so that no one person is going to wreck another one because of the super power of money.

Realisticly?  I'm sure FFG will find a time in the future (given that Netrunner continues to run for a long time) where they don't see as many sales of the older cycles.  At that point, I can see the company doing one of two things: they will either roll up an entire cycle and sell it as a bulk set at less of a price (say the entire Spin Cycle as one whole purchase) or they will try and discontinue the set and put it into archive.

All of that being said, my suggestion to you is to NOT be behind more then one cycle of cards.  Right now, if you don't have the whole Genesis Cycle, you need to get it.  Also, if you don't have a few packs of the Spin Cycle, you're a little behind.  And if you don't have Creation and Control, I feel that your deck building options aren't as robust as they could be.  I'm not saying you won't be able to make a deck.  But the newer cycles, C&C and H&P all have some 'golden' cards that are defining the meta of the game right now.  You can still play, but competitive play will be seeing people playing along with the meta.

EDIT:

A few months ago, FFG did mention that they will be cycling out current sets of cards as being tournament viable.  Much the same way that Magic has a Type 1 and Type 2, Netrunner will only have the latest 6 cycles active at any one time.  Meaning that when we get to the 8th cycle, Genesis and Spin cycle will be phased out of tournament play.  This does NOT mean that they'll end production on these cards, but it's a pretty good guess.

Answer (score 4):

FFG made some promise when they started their LCG (Living Card Game) model, and this promise includes the fact that there should never ever be a concept of rarity in their card game. All cards should be as easily accessible.

This also includes the fact that they will re-produce older packs if there is a demand.